# Why do I never receive 410/device is inactive code from Apple Push Notification's new HTTP2 API?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, apple-push-notifications, http2

I updated an app to use the new APNS HTTP2 API. Previously I used the Apple Feedback Service to know if a device should no longer receive push notifications and it worked well.

It seems this is now wrapped into the new HTTP2 API with status code "410" indicating that the "device is inactive".

In order to test this I sent my device a bunch of notifications, receiving the expected 200 status code each time.

However I then removed the app from my device. A day later if I send notifications to the device I still get 200 status back.

Does this... not work? Am I missing something? I'm using the sandbox/dev environment if that helps.

Comment: hey bro, did you solved this issue? im facing the exact same problem ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39290613/apns-http2-api-not-returning-status-410-after-uninstalling-app

Comment: Check this post:
[How to test Apple Push Notifications Feedback Service?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37410227/how-to-test-apple-push-notifications-feedback-service/39318941#39318941)

Comment: Were you able to detect this issue?