# How to get responce of Push Notification sent via APN to check uninstalled users

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I am sending bulk push notifications to IOS users through APNS , and want to check the response of all the users , to check if any of them has uninstalled the app or not.

Comment: It difficult to know numbers, You can use OneSignal SDK for Push Notifications, It support iOS and Android both they give you dashboard where you see the undelivered tokens from that you can make a guess of uninstalled number of apps

Comment: There is concept called feedback service. You can be explore on that path. Here is the reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37410227/how-to-test-apple-push-notifications-feedback-service

Answer (score 0):

You can't be sure with Push Notifications about anything, Apple never guaranty the delivery of the Notification.

Your notification may never be delivered simply because when you send it he is in high mountain hiking with no data cover, or his phone is turned of, or he has killed your app from task manager (unless your send a VoIP notification), ecc.